# Why are there four connections to a microUSB port when there are only two cables inside the wire?

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering

A microUSB port broke off a PCB I've purchased. I need to solder it back on and was thinking that simply soldering the two internal wires from a USB cord with the male microUSB part clipped off might work better than trying it again with a broken piece.

However, to my surprise, USB ports have only two signals (+/-), yet microUSB ports have four connections that need to pin. What is the purpose of these? Are they necessary, or do I only need two of them? If so, which?

https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Molex/1051330001.JPG

Comment: What is the PCB? Could be that it only needs the power and no data.

Comment: Have a look at the specs again, usb delivers more than just the data

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, @Kevin, but you couldn't have done any research without finding a pinout for USB. If you did then please explain (in your question) what you didn't understand.

Comment: I am asking, why, when I cut a USB cable in half, there are two copper wires (red and black), but when I go to solder a microUSB port, there are four connections. There is no need for a pinout, and I don't understand how a connector determines  the difference between power and data?

Comment: @KevinMauro "There is no need for a pinout", and still you ask the _most trivial thing_ that can be answered by the first page of the wikipedia article about USB.

Comment: because you cut up a ducking non complaint cable. Regular usb cables all have 4 connectors, 5 if we include a shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cable has only to wires, red and black, it is a bootleg cheat cable called "charging-only cable".  These wires don't go to D+/D- pins, they go to VBUS and GND. You can make a little more effort and trace where these wires go on your cut-off connector, and please refer to u-USB connector pinout, for example [**from basic Wikipedia article**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB).